# Let $a$ be a loop in $\mathbb{R}P^2$ which is non-trivial in $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Let $X$ be the space....

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology

Let $a$ be a loop in $\mathbb{R}P^2$ which is non-trivial in $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Let $X$ be the space found by gluing the mobius strip $MB$ to $\mathbb{R}P^2$ by identifying the boundary circle of the mobius strip homeomorphically with $a$. Compute the homology groups of $X$

Let $a: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^2$ be the loop representing a nontrivial element of $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)$.

Let $z: \partial MB \rightarrow im(a)$ be the map gluing the boundary of $MB$ to the image of $a$.

Let $X = \mathbb{R}P^2 \cup_z MB$.

Then, skipping some elementary details, we have a Mayer-Vietoris sequence:

$$0 \rightarrow H_2(X) \xrightarrow{b} H_1(S^1) \xrightarrow{c} H_1(MB) \oplus H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \xrightarrow{d} H_1(X) \xrightarrow{e} H_0(S^1) \xrightarrow{f} H_0(MB) \oplus H_0(\mathbb{R}P^2) \rightarrow H_0(X) \rightarrow 0$$

Also:

$H_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

$H_1(MB) \cong \mathbb{Z}$

$H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$

and the zeroth homology of all the spaces are $\mathbb{Z}$ because they are all path connected.

Here comes the hard part, things are probably about to get messy (if they haven't already >.< lol...)

First of all, it is easy to see that $H_2(X) \cong im(b) \cong ker(c)$.

Also, I believe that $c(1)=(2,\tilde{1})$ where 1 is the generator of $H_1(S^1)$ and $\tilde{1}$ is the non-trivial element of $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)$. Therefore $c$ is injective so $ker(c)=0=H_2(X)$

Groovy. It looks like all that's left to do is calculate $H_1(X)$. To this end, if we look at the reduced homology version of this sequence, keeping in mind that reduced homology is isomorphic to the unreduced homology when the dimension is greater than zero, then this sequence becomes:

$$0 \rightarrow H_2(X) \xrightarrow{b} H_1(S^1) \xrightarrow{c} H_1(MB) \oplus H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \xrightarrow{d} H_1(X) \xrightarrow{e} 0$$

And so we have a S.E.S.:

$$0 \rightarrow \operatorname{im}(c) \xrightarrow{i} H_1(MB) \oplus H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \xrightarrow{d} H_1(X) \rightarrow 0$$

Where $i$ is the inclusion map.

Note that $d$ is surjective. Therefore by the first isomorphism theorem we have:

$$H_1(X) \cong \frac{H_1(MB) \oplus H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)}{\operatorname{im}(c)}$$

I'm really bad at simplifying expressions like these, but I'll try.

$\operatorname{im}(c) = \langle(2,\tilde{1} )\rangle$

$H_1(MB) \oplus H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$

Soooo...

$$H_1(X) \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2}{\langle(2,\tilde{1})\rangle}$$

Is this all correct? If so, is there a way to simplify my expression of $H_1(X)$ into something more intuitive?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your deductions look correct. To figure out what the quotient is count the number of cosets (I will just write their generators): $(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(0,0)$. This gives two possibilities: either $\mathbb{Z}/2 + \mathbb{Z}/2$ or $\mathbb{Z}/4$. The coset of $(1,0)$ has order 4, so it must be the latter.

Comment: For some reason this quotient out part really confuses me, I'd be grateful if you could explain this to me. Modding out $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ by $\langle (2,\tilde{1}) \rangle$ has four cosets? Doesn't the fact that we are modding out by the nontrivial element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ make that factor trivial? and then we are modding out $\mathbb{Z}$ by $\langle 2 \rangle$ and so it becomes $\mathbb{Z}_2$? Perhaps I am not account for the fact that the denominator is not generated by $\langle (2,\tilde{1}) \rangle$ and not $\langle2,\tilde{1} \rangle$. Nevertheless, halp

Comment: An element $x$ in the quotient is of order $n$ if $n$ is the first positive number so that $x^n$ is in the subgroup you are modding out by. So to be order 1 you must be inside the subgroup. The element $(0,1)$ is not inside the subgroup since you can check the subgroup is composed entirely of things that are an even multiple of 2 in the first coordinate and 1 in the second or an odd multiple of 2 in the first coordinate and 0 in the second.

Comment: Try to show that $(G \oplus G) /(g,g)$ is $G$.

Comment: You can also investigate the homomorphism $(a,b) \rightarrow (a+2b)$ from $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4$.

Comment: Doesn't the coset $(1,0)$ have infinite order? For it to have finite order we would need at some point the second coordinate to be formally $\tilde{1}$ which would then be reduced to $\tilde{0}$ if the coordinate on the left was simultaneously an even integer. But the multiples of $(1,0)$ look like $(2,0),(3,0),....$ etc and so it will never have the chance to be the proper form to be reduced

Comment: (2,1)+(2,1)=(4,0)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, $H_2(X) = 0$ is correct since $X$ is non-orientable (containing a MB).
Why do you think $c(1) = (2, \tilde{1})$? The map $H_1(S^1) \to H_1(MB)$ is given by the inclusion and we know $S^1 \cong MB$, so it should map $1$ to $1$, right?

Comment: No, because in the equilanece $S^1 \cong MB$, the boundary of $MB$ goes around the circle that it retracts onto twice.

Comment: oh yeah, right!